# Which is better for Android studio, offline or online

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, ide

I use android studio I downloaded it from the main site and after that I run it and he downloaded sdk files
but I see I saw that I could full download it offline and build apps
my ask
What is the difference between being a program offline or online ?
and how can I full install it offline if it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually no differences. The thing is, offline installer is good when you have to download it from internet caffe since you do not have internet connection at home. That's the purpose of offline installer so you can install it on your computer without internet connection. If you have internet connection then go for online installer.